# Should I keep working on my project on MVC 1.0 or stop and learn MVC 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Few months I've started learning ASP.NET MVC 1.0. Although hard in the beginning, now I've made huge progress so that I'm working on something serious I can show to my colleagues. But, now MVC 2 is almost out there.

Now I would like to know if MVC 1.0 and MVC 2 are profoundly different. In fact, I wonder if I need (first) to finish what I am into or (secondly) I need to stop everything and learn first MVC 2.

To illustrate my point, I'd say: Is migrating from MVC 1.0 to MVC 2 the same scale as migrating from Web Form to MVC 1.0

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Richard - I need to migrate from webforms to mvc, what would be your single top tip to do this

Comment: Books - Pro ASP.NET Apress (Steve Sanderson), The Beer House (Wrox). Tutorial - NerdDinner + Videos from ASP.NET Site. Forums - StackOverflow + ASP.NET Web site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC2 is not a huge leap from MVC1. Most likely your code will run fine on MVC2 as is, with only minor tweaks here and there

here is a guide: http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/10/19/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as migrating from `MVC1` to `MVC2`.

As the later one is an upgraded version, you will only need to learn new features, introduced with it, like

- [**ModelMetadataProvider Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadataprovider(VS.100).aspx)
- [**Model Validator Providers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelvalidatorprovider(VS.100).aspx) and others

  `All the rest is same`.

For instance, if you are using `.Net Framework 4.0`, later on, when version `4.5` or `5.0` comes in, you are not going to migrate! but learn new features in that

Comment: Wrong, they are BREAKING CHANGES. And it's really a mess when you have a 1-year-old application that constantly evolved. Like Added features with the same names as custom developped features, things that does not work anymore (LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression), etc.

In fact, I migrated to .Net 4.0 in the same time and my application could not work at all, I had to re-ntegrate it into a new project class by class, spending 2 days in something that I hoped to be painless...

To answer the question : NO, if you developped simple things accordingly to the 'Microsoft-way' of doing things it'OK

Answer (score 2):

They are **not** profoundly different. Everything you learnt so far on 1.0 is applicable in 2.0. You could start looking at 2.0 [new features](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) though. Quote from Scott Gu's blog:

> ASP.NET MVC 2 is the next significant
>   update of ASP.NET MVC. It is a
>   compatible update to ASP.NET MVC 1 –
>   so all the knowledge, skills, code,
>   and extensions you already have with
>   ASP.NET MVC continue to work and apply
>   going forward

Answer (score 0):

As MVC2 is still a Release Candidate you should check the polices of your company, otherwise I dont think you would have any problem using MVC2, since everything from  MVC1 still works on 2. And you get the beneffits of MVC2.